Creating a Minecraft mod with JSON files for block loot tables but it doesn't register files
I'm creating a minecraft mod with a block named Ruby Block, I setup the JSON files for the block data but they don't seem to work. When I test it in game, I'm able to place the blocks but when I try to mine them with a pickaxe, they don't drop anything and they also mine at the same speed as with a fist.
This is a screenshot of the resources file:

This is the code for my loot table file:
{
  "type": "minecraft:block",
  "pools": [
    {
      "bonus_rolls": 0.0,
      "conditions": [
        {
          "condition": "minecraft:survives_explosion"
        }
      ],
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "name": "ezrafirstmod:ruby_block"
        }
      ],
      "rolls": 1.0
    }
  ],
  "random_sequence": "ezrafirstmod:blocks/ruby_block"
}

This is my mineable pickaxe.json file:
{
  "replace": false,
  "value": [
    "ezrafirstmod:ruby_ore",
    "ezrafirstmod:ruby_block"
  ]
}

If this is also helpful I have the code for my block:
public static final RegistryObject<Block> RUBY_BLOCK = registerBlock("ruby_block",
    () -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of()
        .strength(2f)
        .requiresCorrectToolForDrops()
        .sound(SoundType.AMETHYST)));

I've made sure that the directory to the loot table and mineable JSON files are correct, I've also made sure that the actual JSON files themselves don't have any issues with them. I compared the file directory and JSON file to the base Minecraft blocks and it seems correct. Can anyone help me figure out if I'm doing something wrong?
If you need me to post more code from my project I can.
